# Trigger a script on windows remote environment (VM) using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, openssh

I have 2 windows servers, one server(development) has Jenkins on it and both the servers have OPEN SSH installed in them.
I want to trigger the script(batch script) on my testing server through Jenkins. I tried writing the pipeline but it is showing an error.

I refered to https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin and wrote a pipeline as given below.

```
node {
def remote = [http://inb*****.com]
remote.name = 'inb***'
remote.host = 'http://inb*****.com'
remote.user = 'jenkinsSSH'
remote.password = '********34'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
stage('Remote SSH') {
 writeFile file: 'abc.bat', text: 'ls -lrt'
 sshScript remote: remote, script: "abc.bat"
}
}
```

The output which I am getting is given below,

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 12: unexpected token: } @ line 12, column 1.
}
^

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:100)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:433)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have written a simple batch file - " echo hello " and saved it as abc.bat in the test server.
This is where I am stuck, If there is another method to run the script on the testing server through Jenkins then also please let me know it will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in this line:

> `def remote = [http://inb*****.com]`

It should be

```
def remote = [:]
```

to create an empty map.